# Velocitas eradico — "get rid of speed" or "with speed, eliminate"

Tags: motto

The US Navy's railgun project's badge (see [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QO_zXuOQy6A) at timecode 00:14) has the motto "Velocitas Eradico" — I have no formal instruction in Latin, but my familiarity with Romance languages and etymology leads me to believe the translation would be "With speed, eliminate/destroy [the target]" — that is: the railgun fires projectiles so fast the need for an explosive warhead is eliminated. To double-check this I put it into Google Translate and it gave me "get rid of speed" — which seems like the complete opposite of what the railgun project is about :S

Is either translation correct? Or are both wrong?

Comment: It's funny that they get this stuff wrong but I'm pretty sure they we're going for something like "speed kills".

Comment: Once they fix the grammar, there's a good reason to have the motto in Latin. "Speed" is ambiguous (since it could refer to a drug) in a way that *velocitas* is not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree with varro that neither translation is correct.
The most sensible translation seems to be indeed "I, the speed, eradicate".
It's a weird personification, but possible.
However, it is more likely to be wrong than clever.

I suspect that someone looked up the two words in a dictionary but did not realize that the words might need to be inflected.
They are precisely in the form listed in many [Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).
Therefore the first person singular is possibly coincidental.

If you want to say "I eradicate the speed", the speed needs to be in accusative: *Velocitatem eradico*.
If you want to say "I eradicate with speed", the speed should be in ablative: *Velocitate eradico*.
If you want to replace "I eradicate" with "we eradicate", just replace *eradico* with *eradicamus*.
The English verb "eradicate" is just one possible translation for *eradicare*; there are also other options like "get rid of" or "eliminate" as you suggested.

I know, they are not likely to change the wording now, but I just wanted to record how the thing should be written properly.
As with any language, you should not be using it in important situations without consulting an expert.

Comment: Maybe the real translation is a hidden message: "This device was built by a bunch of clueless know-nothings" ;)

Comment: @alephzero I will leave any such conclusions to be drawn by readers. (And in their defense, my experience suggests that operating weapons and writing Latin are rather independent skill sets.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta What if the weapon was a pilum or gladius?

Comment: I selected this as the Accepted answer despite fewer votes because of the extra detail you provided. Thank you!

Comment: @alephzero at risk of being off-topic, when it comes to railguns that is a horrifying thought.

Answer (score 6):

Neither translation is correct, and I suspect the Latin motto was intended to mean something other than what it actually says.  As it reads, though, it means something like: "I, speed, eradicate".  Seems odd, to say the least.

Comment: Leave it to the US government & military to not actually consult with an expert on something this simple.

Comment: @C. M. Weimer It's not only the US government and military. Some years ago, I managed to embarrass the San Diego PD by pointing out that their motto was incorrect Latin!

Answer (score 2):

I add another possibility to Joonas Ilmavirta's excellent answer: "speed eradicates", which would be translated as *velocitas eradicat*.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for the answer!